# ExapandableListView not work

Tags: android, expandablelistview

```
package com.icube.platform;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.icube.timbodi.R;
import com.icube.timbodi.calendar.CalendarView;
import com.icube.timbodi.player.ChosePlayerView;
import com.icube.timbodi.scorecenter.PlayerlistActivity;
import com.icube.timbodi.user.ChangePassword;
import com.icube.timbodi.user.DashBoard;
import com.icube.timbodi.user.LandingActivity;
import com.icube.timbodi.user.UserFans;

 class MenuLabel 
 {
    public Button button;
        public MenuLabel() {

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public MenuLabel(Button button ) {
                this.button=button;
                this.button.setText("ram");
        }

        public void setText(String str)
        {
            button.setText(str);

        }

    }




public class SlidingAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    MenuLabel data[] = null;
    String[] menuLabel;
    int[] menuIcon;
    Intent intent;
    String[][] subMenuLabel={{"1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"},{"9","8","7","6"},{"5","4","3"},{"3","2","1"},{"2","3","4","5"},{"1","3","2"}};
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;


    public SlidingAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, MenuLabel[] data,String[] menuLabel,int[] menuIcon)
    {
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    this.menuLabel=menuLabel;this.menuIcon=menuIcon;
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@+++++++++++++++++@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");

    }

   /* @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        SlidingLabelHolder holder = null;
        final int p=position;

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new SlidingLabelHolder();
            holder.button=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.sliding_menu);
                holder.button.setText("    "+menuLabel[position]);
                Drawable img = context.getResources().getDrawable( menuIcon[position] );
                img.setBounds( 0, 0, 40, 40 );

                holder.button.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
                holder.button.setId(position);
                holder.button.setOnClickListener(this);




            //row.setTag(0, holder);    
            //row.setTag(holder);



        MenuLabel menuLabel = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(menuLabel.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(menuLabel.icon);

        return row;
    }
    */

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String str[]=subMenuLabel[groupPosition];
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

      System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@dev@@@@@@@@@@+++++++++++++++++@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
       Button button=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_menu);
       button.setText(">"+str[childPosition]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        System.out.println("1"+"##############");
        return subMenuLabel[groupPosition].length-1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        System.out.println("2"+"##############"+ (menuLabel.length-1));
        return menuLabel.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {System.out.println("3"+"##############");
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {System.out.println("4"+"##############");
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int position, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        SlidingLabelHolder holder = null;
        final int p=position;

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new SlidingLabelHolder();
            holder.button=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.sliding_menu);
                holder.button.setText("    "+menuLabel[position]);
                Drawable img = context.getResources().getDrawable( menuIcon[position] );
                img.setBounds( 0, 0, 40, 40 );

                holder.button.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
                holder.button.setId(position);
                holder.button.setOnClickListener(this);
                System.out.println("5"+"##############");



            //row.setTag(0, holder);    
            //row.setTag(holder);



        MenuLabel menuLabel = data[position];

        return row;
    }


     static class SlidingLabelHolder
        {
          Button button;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*switch(view.getId())
            {
            case 0 :
            {
                Intent mi = new Intent(context , DashBoard.class);
                context.startActivity(mi);
                break;
            }
            case 1:
                {
                    Intent mi = new Intent(context , CalendarView.class);
                    context.startActivity(mi);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent t = new Intent(context , PlayerlistActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(t);
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                Intent mi = new Intent(context , ChosePlayerView.class);
                context.startActivity(mi);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
                Intent mi = new Intent(context , UserFans.class);
                context.startActivity(mi);
                break;
            case 5:
                  Intent i = new Intent(context, ChangePassword.class);
                //view.getContext().startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 6:
                AlertDialog.Builder a=new Builder(context);
                a.setMessage("Do you want to log out from this app");
                a.setTitle("Logout ?");
                a.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        intent = new Intent(context, LandingActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
              a.setNegativeButton("cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                  }
              });
                a.show();
                break;

            }*/

        }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
ArrayList<GroupHeader>      m_list = new ArrayList<GroupHeader> ();
ArrayList<String> sub_items = new ArrayList<String>();
sub_items.add("sub_item1");
sub_items.add("sub_item2");
sub_items.add("sub_item2");
GroupHeader group1 = new GroupHeader("Group1", sub_items);
GroupHeader group1 = new GroupHeader("Group2", sub_items);
GroupHeader group1 = new GroupHeader("Group3", sub_items);

CustomExpandableListAdapter ELA_adapter     = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), groupList);
expandableListView.setAdapter(ELA_adapter);

public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        private Context                     m_context;
        private ArrayList<GroupHeader>      m_list;
        private LayoutInflater              m_inflater;

        public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GroupHeader> list){
            m_context   = context;
            m_inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(m_context);
            m_list      = list;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return m_list.get(groupPosition).getSub_items().get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final String item                   = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition); 

            convertView 
            -------------------------
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return m_list.get(groupPosition).getSub_items().size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return m_list.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return m_list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
            final GroupHeader group = (GroupHeader) getGroup(groupPosition);    

            convertView             
            -------------------------------------------------

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            /* used to make the notifyDataSetChanged() method work */
            super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
    }

    public class GroupHeader {
    public GroupHeader(){

    }

    public GroupHeader(String key, ArrayList<String> value){
        this.header = key;
        this.sub_items  = value;
    }
    String header = "";
    ArrayList<String> sub_items = new ArrayList<String>();
    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getSub_items() {
        return sub_items;
    }
    public void setSub_items(ArrayList<String> sub_items) {
        this.sub_items = sub_items;
    }

}
```